# Saving .ASCX files in Visual Studio 2010 takes 3 minutes

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have a control with 2150 lines of code that contains some Telerik controls. Each time I save in Visual Studio, it takes around 3 minutes even if I just changed one character!

This happens only for the `.ASCX` files, but not the code behind. I am not using any extra tools like Resharper or JustCode.

How can I fix this? Where should I look?

Comment: Did you install service pack 1 for Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: @Oded, i am using this VS in my company, i am not sure if SP installed or not, VS version is : 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel. should i reinstall it to make sure?

Comment: You need to get and install SP1. http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=23691

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slowness with saving `.ascx` (and `.aspx`) files was an issue with Visual Studio 2010.

Service Pack 1 solved this issue.

It can be downloaded [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=23691).

Comment: unfortunately, the problem happened again with SP1, after deep research i have found that the problem is the toolbox. I also noticed that when you close the toolbox the problem disappears and Visa Versa. I've got the key answer from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407021(VS.100).aspx)